# Scraping with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to **scrape** data from some pages. I have a problem with loop -> each red-border rectangle I want to fill-in with "i" parameter, which denotes number of pages. Could someone tell me how to do it?

```
Sub czwarta()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 6 To i = 100

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 0 (6)", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Źródło = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://wcn.pl/archive?page=6""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data0 = Źródło{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Zmieniono typ"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{""Zdjęcie/Numer"", type text}, {""Opis"", type text}, {""Stan"", type text}, {""Cena"", Currency.Type}, {""Data"", type date}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Zmieniono typ"""
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 0 (6)"";Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$131")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 0 (6)]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_0__6"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=30
Range("A157").Select
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code as text too (screenshot is helpful, but we can't copy/paste it)

Comment: I tried for next loop, but I don`t know how to enter the "i" parameter into code

Comment: You concatenate with `&`.

Comment: I tried for example: "Table 0 "&(i) but it doesn`t work

Comment: `"Table 0 (" & i & ")"`.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but who to used it in https...?

Comment: If it's easier, you could use `Replace`.